# Document DB query

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to query one of my documents from documentDB but it doesn't appear to be working, this is how i set it up:

**NoSQLService:**

```
private INoSQLProvider client;
private static IContainer container;

public NoSQLService(INoSQLProvider provider)
{
    client = provider;
}

public static dynamic QueryDocument<T>(Uri reference, FeedOptions queryOptions)
{
    var documentDB = container.Resolve<INoSQLProvider>();
    return documentDB.QueryDocumentAsync(reference, queryOptions);
}
```

**INoSQLProvider:**

```
IOrderedQueryable<Document> QueryDocumentAsync(Uri reference, FeedOptions queryOptions);
```

**AzureDocumentDBService**

`AzureDocumentDBService` inherits from `INoSQLProvider`

```
private readonly IDocumentClient client;

public IOrderedQueryable<Document> QueryDocumentAsync (Uri reference, FeedOptions queryOptions)
{
    return client.CreateDocumentQuery(reference, queryOptions);
}
```

**AzureDocumentDBTest**

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions();

Documents document = new Documents();

document.id = "112";

queryOptions.MaxItemCount = -1;

var reference = NoSQLService.CreateDocumentUri("ppsession1", "callumtest");
IQueryable<Documents> documentQuery = NoSQLService.QueryDocument<Documents>(reference, queryOptions).Where(document.id = "112");

foreach (Documents documents in documentQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tRead {0}", documents);

}
```

When I run the test I get an exception:

> Microsoft,CSparp.RuntimeBuilder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Where'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `dynamic` from `NoSQLService.QueryDocument` and then trying to apply Linq extension method `Where` on it. Which you cannot do. You would have to cast it to something that can work with that extension.

So either change your `NoSQLService` from using the dynamic

```
public static IQueryable<Document> QueryDocument<T>(Uri reference, FeedOptions queryOptions)
{
    var documentDB = container.Resolve<INoSQLProvider>();
    return documentDB.QueryDocumentAsync(reference, queryOptions);
}
```

or cast the result in your test

```
var reference = NoSQLService.CreateDocumentUri("ppsession1", "callumtest");
IQueryable<Document> documentQuery = ((IQueryable<Document>)NoSQLService.QueryDocument<Document>(reference, queryOptions)).Where(document => document.id == "112");
```

Comment: I've tried both but they both threw and exception: COM.PixelPin.NoSQLService.Tests.AzureDocumentDbTests.TestQueryDocument threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[COM.PixelPin.NoSQLService.Tests.Documents]'.

Comment: Just noticed that you have two different types for `Document`. Is that a typo? I edited my answer to match what should be from the service